# Can't get Github Colorpicker to work for Android using Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, color-picker

I want to use a colorpicker for my android application. I tried to get it working by following the steps on github. I can open the Dialog but don't really understand how to return a color. Here is the Github dependencie I'd like to use: https://github.com/skydoves/ColorPickerView.
Edit: I want to use it as a dialog that I open over a button that calls this function.

```
private fun openColorPickerDialog(): String {

    val builder = ColorPickerDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Choose custom color!")
    builder.setPreferenceName("MyColorPickerDialog")
    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.confirm), ColorEnvelopeListener { envelope, fromUser -> })
    builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialogInterface, i -> dialogInterface.dismiss() })
    builder.show()

    return
}
```

Here's what I have so far. It opens the dialog and now I want to return if possible a Hex-Color string what I then can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get your color picked in Hex

```
builder.setColorListener(new ColorEnvelopeListener() {
@Override
public void onColorSelected(ColorEnvelope envelope, boolean fromUser) {
    textView.setText("#" + envelope.getHexCode());
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you've solved it by now, but for whoever else is having this issue:

The ColorPickerDialog Builder overloads setPositiveButton(). If you've you used AlertDialog Builder, you are probably use to:

```
.setPositiveButton("Confirm"){ someFunction() }
```

However, if you want the color, you need to use the overloaded setPositiveButton() function as follows:

```
.setPositiveButton("Confirm", ColorEnvelopeListener(){colorEnvelope,_->
                Log.d("TAG","${colorEnvelope.color}")
            })
```

This give you the selected color.

If you're curious, here's the overloaded function:

```
public Builder setPositiveButton(
    CharSequence text, final ColorPickerViewListener colorListener) {
  super.setPositiveButton(text, getOnClickListener(colorListener));
  return this;
}
```